# How to import data from Blockchain.info to Excel

Tags: blockchain.info

can anyone explain how to transfer data from Blockchain.info to Excel. I am not familiar with the CSV format.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: What sort of data are you trying to get from Blockchain.info?

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain.info has a list of API endpoints to make it easy to collect data.

[blockchain.info/api](https://blockchain.info/api)

Depending on which data set you want, you can typically add `?format=csv` to the end of the query to get results in csv format, or `?format=json` if you'd prefer JSON. Once you have the data in a .csv file, you can simply [open the file in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba), which has native support for .csv files.

Answer (score 0):

The .csv format is 'comma separated variables', and is easily imported into Excel.

However, most of the blockchain data available will be a list with varying numbers of fields. This does not lend itself to a .csv file, so they're only available as .json files. These are not easily converted to simple m*n table that Excel will like.

Summary: whether you'll be able to do what you want to do depends on which data you want.